# react component this.value is null even when it's populated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

Here a simplified version of a React component I have:

```
class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {key : 10 };
        this.value = null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchValueFromServer();
        this.fetchSecondValueFromServer();
    }

    fetchValueFromServer() {
        fetch_value_from_server(this.state.key).then( (value) => {
            this.value = value;     
        }); 
    }

    fetchSecondValueFromServer() {
        is_ready(this.value).then(() => {
            console.log("there");       
        }); 
    }

}
```

I expect to see the console.log("there") printed but `this.value` always remains null, even thou is set in the `fetchValueFromServer`. Why is this?
if you are curious to how `is_ready` looks it's a simple promise:

```
function is_ready(variable) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let interval = setInterval(() => 
        { 
            if (variable) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                resolve();
            }

        }, 100);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the logic of the `is_ready` function. It looks like you want that function to repeatedly check if that value is there, then resolve when it is. However, because of how closures in JS work, that `variable` argument will only ever have one value in the context of that function's body, even after `this.value` changes. Look at this small example:

```js
let secret = 'not found yet'

function checkSecret(secretArg) {
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(secretArg)
  }, 500)
}

checkSecret(secret)
setTimeout(() => { secret = 'secret found!' }, 1000)
```

This code will always print 'not found yet', because it's checking the `secretArg` variable that's been assigned locally, and not the `secret` variable directly.

Comment: yeah thank you, I figured that one out.  I hope in the future we can pass by ref.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to resolve with the `variable` value within the function `is_ready`, like so:

```
resolve(variable);
```

Then add a param to your console log to determine more, like so:

```
fetchSecondValueFromServer() {
    is_ready(this.value).then((returnValue) => {
        console.log("there", returnValue);       
    }); 
}
```

Comment: if you are suggesting we must pass a parameter to resolve, that wasn't it I tried it

Answer (score -1):

figured it, the value in `is_ready` is passed by value! Javascript needs to implement & so we can pass crap by ref!

Comment: someone didn't like my pass by reference comment